# What is the proper way to separate an SVG path into its visible components in SED?

Tags: svg, sed

I have an `SVG` file with a font on it. I would like all the individual letters to be on separate paths (for easier parsing and stuff like that).
The thing is, all the letters are on the same path.

I have tried using the following `SED` script:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

s/ M/\"\/\>\n\<path d=\"M/g
```

(the `SVG` in question starts and ends it's paths like that, so I don't think that should be a problem.)

However, this results in a lot of areas being filled in that weren't filled in in the original. I thought `M` meant move to a specific place.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a problem that is too big for `SED`?

EDIT:

link to my code and SVG-s:
https://gitlab.com/smeagolthellama/glyphgenerator/tree/master

SVG's are in `fonts/`. Base file is `black_path1.svg`, result is `black_path1_seperated.svg` (sorry for the typo, will fix).

Comment: @enxaneta is there any way to do it automatically with something like inkscape or ImageMagick? The letters are separate, and on a transparent background.

Comment: I believe the only way of doing it is manual editing. Can you add your SVG code or at least a link to it?

Comment: @enxaneta added a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the letter A: after drawing the external part you need to "cut off" the middle triangle. To do this you may need to move to a different point and draw the triangle in opposite direction. You do this with the M or m command. If you split the path by the M you will get two paths: the exterior of the A and the little triangle both filled. You may need to edit your SVG manually.

This is how I did it: I opened your SVG in Illustrator, I've grouped together the paths for each letter, next I joined the paths for the same letter in one path.

This is for example the letter b:

```css
svg{width:45%;border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg  viewBox="355 32.006 5 5">
<g id="_b">
 <path d="M357.427,34.199c0.018,0,0.035,0,0.052,0.002c0.242,0.018,0.433,0.139,0.572,0.363c0.121,0.197,0.182,0.431,0.182,0.7
  c0,0.278-0.099,0.539-0.296,0.781c-0.197,0.242-0.413,0.375-0.646,0.397c-0.043,0.004-0.086,0.006-0.128,0.006
  c-0.227,0-0.442-0.06-0.646-0.181c0.018-0.839,0.029-1.414,0.034-1.723c0.144-0.121,0.312-0.213,0.504-0.276
  C357.197,34.222,357.321,34.199,357.427,34.199z"/>
 <path d="M356.604,32.006l-0.559,0.054l0.006,0.572l-0.182,0.014l0.014,0.135l0.175-0.014c0.004,0.108,0.004,0.182,0,0.222
  l-0.188,0.014l0.014,0.134l0.182-0.013l0.047,3.608l0.397-0.027v-0.162c0.184,0.126,0.435,0.195,0.754,0.209
  c0.015,0,0.03,0,0.045,0c0.337,0,0.649-0.144,0.938-0.432c0.296-0.3,0.444-0.657,0.444-1.07c0-0.413-0.104-0.747-0.31-1.003
  c-0.202-0.256-0.458-0.39-0.767-0.404c-0.021-0.001-0.042-0.001-0.062-0.001c-0.37,0-0.699,0.115-0.988,0.344l0.02-1.111
  l0.424-0.034l-0.014-0.134l-0.411,0.034l0.007-0.216l0.404-0.027l-0.013-0.134l-0.391,0.027L356.604,32.006z"/>
 <path d="M357.29,35.055c-0.059,0-0.11,0.022-0.155,0.067c-0.045,0.041-0.067,0.092-0.067,0.155c0,0.059,0.022,0.11,0.067,0.155
  c0.045,0.044,0.096,0.067,0.155,0.067c0.063,0,0.117-0.022,0.162-0.067c0.041-0.045,0.061-0.097,0.061-0.155
  c0-0.062-0.022-0.117-0.067-0.161C357.404,35.076,357.353,35.055,357.29,35.055z"/>
</g>
</svg>

<svg  viewBox="355 32.006 5 5">
<g id="b">
 <path d="M357.427,34.199c0.018,0,0.035,0,0.052,0.002c0.242,0.018,0.433,0.139,0.572,0.363c0.121,0.197,0.182,0.431,0.182,0.7
  c0,0.278-0.099,0.539-0.296,0.781c-0.197,0.242-0.413,0.375-0.646,0.397c-0.043,0.004-0.086,0.006-0.128,0.006
  c-0.227,0-0.442-0.06-0.646-0.181c0.018-0.839,0.029-1.414,0.034-1.723c0.144-0.121,0.312-0.213,0.504-0.276
  C357.197,34.222,357.321,34.199,357.427,34.199z
   
    M356.604,32.006l-0.559,0.054l0.006,0.572l-0.182,0.014l0.014,0.135l0.175-0.014c0.004,0.108,0.004,0.182,0,0.222
  l-0.188,0.014l0.014,0.134l0.182-0.013l0.047,3.608l0.397-0.027v-0.162c0.184,0.126,0.435,0.195,0.754,0.209
  c0.015,0,0.03,0,0.045,0c0.337,0,0.649-0.144,0.938-0.432c0.296-0.3,0.444-0.657,0.444-1.07c0-0.413-0.104-0.747-0.31-1.003
  c-0.202-0.256-0.458-0.39-0.767-0.404c-0.021-0.001-0.042-0.001-0.062-0.001c-0.37,0-0.699,0.115-0.988,0.344l0.02-1.111
  l0.424-0.034l-0.014-0.134l-0.411,0.034l0.007-0.216l0.404-0.027l-0.013-0.134l-0.391,0.027L356.604,32.006z
 
    M357.29,35.055c-0.059,0-0.11,0.022-0.155,0.067c-0.045,0.041-0.067,0.092-0.067,0.155c0,0.059,0.022,0.11,0.067,0.155
  c0.045,0.044,0.096,0.067,0.155,0.067c0.063,0,0.117-0.022,0.162-0.067c0.041-0.045,0.061-0.097,0.061-0.155
  c0-0.062-0.022-0.117-0.067-0.161C357.404,35.076,357.353,35.055,357.29,35.055z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Please see the full SVG in [codepen](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/40cb2f62fc9db082d1344e0167277f32?editors=1101)

Comment: Wow! Thank you! This is far more than I would have expected. Not to be picky, but if I ever have the same problem again, is there a way to have it automatically do it (as in a script)?

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't. However the fact that you separated the paths was of invaluable help.